# RegEx terminate match group with optional literal

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to match everything after a symbol that may or may not have a closing.

With a string like `adsf>adsfasdfad<sfad>sfadfadf` I'm trying to match after `>` but that can be interrupted with `<`

I've tried many iterations, the closest I can get to working is `\>(.*?)(?:\<?)` but this still captures `sfad` between `<` and `>` where in actuality I would want to ignore `sfad`

I'm trying to get the string to match like this:
`adsf>adsfasdfad<sfad>sfadfadf` would have two matches
`adsfasdfad`
`sfadfadf`

If no `<` is present, the whole rest of the string would match. There is no limit to the number of `>` and `<` that may occur.

Comment: [`>([^<>]*)`](https://regex101.com/r/wN9tI9/2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Tushar noted, this should accomplish what you're looking for, but you'll need to check the first capture group for this (`$1` in substitutions):

```
>([^><]*)
```

I don't know your use case, but if you're also hoping to match backslash-escaped `<` or `>` characters, you could do something like this:

```
>((?:\\<|\\>|[^><])*)
```

[Test here](https://regex101.com/r/zO8uV5/1)

Code in action:

```js
var input = 'adsf>adsfasdfad<sfad>sfadfadf';
var regex = />([^><]*)/g;

var matches, output = [];
while (matches = regex.exec(input)) {
    output.push(matches[1]);
}
document.write(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

Or try this:

```
(?:>([^<>]+))
```

[DEMO.](https://regex101.com/r/rT6cW5/1)

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely do this with following regex:

```
/(?:\>)([^<]+)/g
```

See demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/hN8aZ3/1)

Matched content will be in `$1`

Output:

```
adsfasdfad
sfadfadf
```